# Nyquist / Shannon theorems for different sampling models.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, fourier-analysis, signal-processing

It is well known that to be able to *sample* a band-limited function without introducing distortion, we need to sample with twice the rate of the highest frequency. This is the **Nyquist / Shannon** sampling theorem which most students encounter in their first signal processing / Fourier analysis course.

However, do there exist any other theorems for other models of sampling. Say for example another type of sampling performs:

$$a[n] = \frac{1}{\Delta_t}\int_{-\Delta_t/2}^{\Delta_t/2}f(n\Delta_t+t)dt$$

What effect would that have on a sampling theorem if we wanted to derive one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use a dimensionality argument at least if the time window is finite.

Since the signal is frequency limited there is a one-to-one mapping of the fourier transform to a periodic extension of it. And then the reverse fourier transform is back to a a discrete function (with the support of the original).

This basically means that you have a bijection from the function space to $\mathbb C^{2\Delta f\Delta T}$. So any tuple representation must at least have that many elements.

That is no matter how you sample (using a linear mapping to samples) you cannot circumvent the Nyquist criterion on the number of samples required.

Comment: This sounds interesting, although I can't say I understand why it would be incircumventable. Maybe I simply need to think more about it.

Comment: You can recover $f$ from $f(t_n )$ if $|t_n-t_{n-1}| < B/2$ but it doesn't tell us the way to recover it. By linearity it will be $f(t) = \sum_n h_n(t-t_n) f(t_n)$ but $h_n$ may be quite complicated. In your case the idea is similar. @mathreadler

Comment: @skyling To make this rigorous you need to show the kernel of the linear map $T : f \mapsto \langle f,w_n \rangle$ is $\{0\}$ using that $f(t) = \int_{-B/2}^{B/2} \hat{f}(\xi)e^{2i \pi \xi t}d\xi$

Comment: @reuns what is $w_n$, and could you please give a reference for your idea?